# Scale button`s icon in Flex for mobile applications

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air, icons, flash-builder

Use Flex 4.5.1 and when add icons to the button is so curve effect of scaling. 
Prompt how to make a proportional scaling icons?[image: No aspect ratio icon]

```
<s:Button width="100%" height="50" label="Create new map" click="button3_clickHandler(event)"
              fontSize="22" icon="@Embed('icons/001-folder.png')">
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a custom skin looks like if you let it copy the default skin for you you'll have an object in there with an id of iconDisplay (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/skins/SparkButtonSkin.html#iconDisplay) that'll probably help to see how it's currently being sized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to create custom skin for button and do the same in commitProperties

```
override protected function commitProperties():void
{
      super.commitProperties();

      if(iconDisplay){
           iconDisplay.scaleMode = BitmapScaleMode.LETTERBOX;
      }
}
```

Comment: I did not want to use the new skins, but I had to. Thank you for your decision. It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

try add creation complete handler and set btn.iconDisplay.scaleMode to BitmapScaleMode.LETTERBOX

```
protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    btn.iconDisplay.scaleMode = BitmapScaleMode.LETTERBOX
}


<s:Button id="btn" creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)" width="100%" height="50" label="Create new map" click="button3_clickHandler(event)"
              fontSize="22" icon="@Embed('icons/001-folder.png')">
```